# Can Eclipse check exception type like in IntelliJ with <cntl><n>?

Tags: eclipse

With IntelliJ you can determine whether an exception is checked or unchecked. Does eclipse easily provide a feature like this?

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. From eclipse, to view if an exception is checked or unchecked, or for that matter any information concerning a Java class *click Navigate->Open Type...  and select it from the Outline View*. This navigation was what I was asking about.  Of course, a checked exception will extend IOException, while an unchecked exception will extend RuntimeException.

Comment: To quickly open the outline, simply press `Ctrl`+`O`.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for a quick popup or <kbd>F4</kbd> for the *Type Hiearchy* view to get type hierarchy information. If the `Exception` extends `RuntimeException`, it's unchecked. All other Exceptions, including `IOException` are checked.

Comment: Unfortunately the `F4` binding seems to be not working in Eclipse 2023-03.